# How can I resize a non-square image in Rcpp using OpenCV, without having its content modified?

Tags: c++, r, opencv, rcpp

I'm trying to use the resize function from OpenCV (release 3.3.0) inside of a Rcpp function and then return the resized image back to R. I know this can be done in R, but I want to test the method for performance comparisons.

I need to transpose the armadillo matrix so OpenCV can work on the image. Then the resize is done, and the image is transposed again to be able to convert it to armadillo matrix again. The problem is, when I resize the image and I transpose it, I get the "twisted" images that you can see below. How can I do this correctly without getting modifications in the image, other than the resizing?

The function is described in the following code, and the usage and output images  are also below:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat resizeImage(arma::mat& armaMat, double resizeRatio) {

  cv::Mat opencvMat(armaMat.n_rows, armaMat.n_cols, CV_64FC1, armaMat.memptr());
  cv::Mat opencvMatTransposed(opencvMat.t());

  cv::Mat resizedImage;
  cv::resize(opencvMatTransposed, resizedImage, cv::Size(), resizeRatio, resizeRatio, INTER_AREA);
  cv::Mat resizedImageTransposed(resizedImage.t());

  arma::mat outputArmaMat(reinterpret_cast<double*>(resizedImageTransposed.data), resizedImageTransposed.rows, resizedImageTransposed.cols);

  return outputArmaMat;
}
```

I prepare the input for the function, which is a grayscale image, and then I call the function like this:

```
library(EBImage)
inputImage <- readImage("~/pathToImage/image.jpg")
inputImage <- EBImage::channel(inputImage, "gray")
display(inputImage)
outputImage <- resizeImage(imageData(inputImage), 0.99)
display(outputImage)
outputImage <- resizeImage(imageData(inputImage), 0.5)
display(outputImage)
```

Original Image:

[image: Original Input Image]

0.99 Resized Input Image:

[image: 0.99 Resized Input Image]

0.5 Resized Input Image:

[image: 0.5 Resized Input Image]

I must be missing something really obvious, but I can't make the resize function work as intended. I think the problem might be conversion between OpenCV and EBImage formats.

**EDIT:** the algorithm works perfectly fine for square images. They get resized correctly and the output image is showing as intended. The problem is only happening with non-square images.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does that `Size()` call supposed to return?

Comment: It returns a size object of dimensions (0,0). The size for the new image is computed using fx and fy parameters (resizeRatio in my code). See the documentation: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html

Comment: Once I write bmp file in my hand-write code,  it occurs something like yours. The reason was that I don't adjust the row offset right. (In bmp, the row size in byte must be alligened in 4x bytes). Hope this information is useful for you.

Comment: I already tried to set the size of the output image prior to applying the resize function, but to no avail. Thanks for trying anyway, Silencer.